# Load balancing multiple sites with one load balancer

Tags: unix, load-balancing

I'm wondering if it's possible to loadbalance two sites from one load balancer running HAproxy (or pound or varnish or some other *nix based balancer).  We have
dev.site.com that load balances to dev1.site.com and dev2.site.com and 
qae.site.com that load balances to qae1.site.com and qae2.site.com and it would be nice if we just had one machine handling the load balancing for both of these non-production sites.

I've been dinkering around with a ZXTM balancer that we got from our host and for all it's expensive niceness, it wont balance more than one site per physical machine.  Is this an actual limitation due to trying to balance over port 80?  I'd think that there'd be a way around that ala apache's virtualhost:80 setup, but then again, I'm not that well versed in networking.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's always Squid. It has the advantage of also being a caching proxy, but you can turn that functionality off if you don't want it. I recommend these links:

[Squid wiki - example config for multiple sites](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Reverse/MultipleWebservers)

[Sun-provided instructions on load balancing with Squid](http://wikis.sun.com/display/WebStack/Using+Squid+as+a+Load+Balancer)

Comment: Great, those examples were just the type of thing I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Every ZXTM LB I've come across can do this with multiple sites, although I'm no expert on those products sorry (I'm more of a Foundry-man myself), so I suspect you'll be able to get it to work if you get the time to dig deeper. Best of luck.

Comment: We've been messing with it a bit and it appears it's a limit imposed by the host we have (which is money grubbing and lame, but they're still a good host).  Either way, the ZXTM is reserved for production and I'd prefer to have something else (and free) balancing non-prod.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to load balance thousands of sites with a single load balancer running LVS, ZXTM, Big IP or cisco.

If cost is an issue LVS is a great solution. http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/

Zeus is able to do it also, support.zeus.com/zlb/media/docs/userguide.pdf chapter 6.

There is no limitation on load balancing over port 80. The http get request sends a name, if the name matches a vhost, files are returned. This is how the same server can server thousands of vhosts.